# Tipagem de dados

Tags: ionic, angular, ionic2, ionic3

tudo bem?

Colocando em prática o que aprendi em angular/ionic, me deparei com algumas dúvidas:

1- Fiz um ion-select com lista de estados vindo do firebase. Quando tipei o model Estados, fique na dúvida se no model eu faço `export interface`  ou `export class` . Vi que posso fazer das duas formas, mas qual diferença e que resultado isso implica?

2- Quando retornei a lista de estados do firebase, utilizei o this.af.database.ref("/estados") e não o this.af.database.list("/estados") como está no curso. Fiquei com dúvida na hora do retorno do service. Pois a sintaxe é diferente e não ficou claro pra mim que tipo e como é este retorno. Veja:

cadastro.ts

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.estados = this.estadosService.listar();
}
```

cadastro.service.ts

```
listar():any{ // este any deveria ser do tipo Estados, correto?
    return this.af.database.ref('/estados')
        .once('value')
        .then( (resposta) => {
            return resposta.val();
        })
        .catch( (erro) => {
            console.log(erro);
        })
}
```

​
Se não consegui explicar bem e quiser ver o código todo para entender melhor minhas dúvidas, segue no github:

[Github​](https://github.com/michelmfreitas/aulas/tree/master/src)

Answer (score 0):

O retorno do metodo Listar() do seu service cadastro é do tipo "any". Isto é, ele é dinâmico. Esse tipo de método é interessante ser utilizado quando se precisa descrever o tipo de variáveis ​​que não se conhece quando estamos escrevendo um aplicativo. E esses valores podem vir de conteúdo dinâmico.

Veja mais em:

> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

No caso do método Listar(), o retorno da chamada não é tipada em nenhum lugar. Seria necessário que você criasse uma model e mapeasse o resultado para esse tipo antes de retornar para o component. Veja mais em:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911348/angular2-map-data-as-specific-object-type